# How to cache playwright-python contexts for testing?

Tags: python, caching, playwright, playwright-python

I am doing some web scraping using [`playwright-python>=1.41`](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python), and have to launch the browser in a headed mode (e.g. `launch(headless=False)`.

For CI testing, I would like to somehow cache the headed interactions with Chromium, to enable offline testing:

- First invocation: uses Chromium to make real-world HTTP transactions
- Later invocations: uses Chromium, but all HTTP transactions read from a cache

How can this be done? I can't find any clear answers on how to do this.

Comment: Maybe [this section](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/network#http-authentication) of the documentation will help?

Comment: How does HTTP authentication help? I am not quite following your suggestion

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize what you were asking earlier. What do you mean by "HTTP transactions"?

Comment: Like logging of all HTTP GET/POST data, so they can be replayed during testing without an internet connection and extra connections

Comment: I wrote a solution for you, but it's in TypeScript not Python... not yet at least

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might solve your problem using HAR-file recording:

1. Run the first test while [recording a HAR-file](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/mock#recording-a-har-file)
2. Storing the HAR-file as an artifact, in your repo or similar in your CI environment
3. Running test again [with recorded HAR-file](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/mock#replaying-from-har)

Here is how to do that with `playwright==1.41.1` and `pytest-playwright==0.3.3`:

```py
import pathlib

import pytest
from playwright.sync_api import Browser, Playwright

CACHE_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / "cache"


@pytest.fixture(name="example_har", scope="session")
def fixture_example_har(playwright: Playwright) -> pathlib.Path:
    har_file = CACHE_DIR / "example.har"
    with (
        playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False) as browser,
        browser.new_page() as page,
    ):
        page.route_from_har(har_file, url="*/**", update=True)
        page.goto("https://example.com/")
    return har_file


def test_caching(browser: Browser, example_har: pathlib.Path) -> None:
    with browser.new_context(offline=True) as context:
        page = context.new_page()
        page.route_from_har(example_har, url="*/**")
        page.goto("https://example.com/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `set_extra_http_headers()` and `set_offline()` methods to cache headed interactions and also launch the browser with a specific cache directory so the same cache is used across multiple invocations of your script.

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

browser.context.set_offline(True)

browser = sync_playwright().chromium.launch(
    headless=False,
    chromium_sandbox=False,
    args=["--disk-cache-dir=/path/to/cache"],
)

browser.context.set_extra_http_headers({"Cache-Control": "max-age=31536000"})

# Do web scraping here

browser.close()
```

Here the `error playwright._impl._errors.Error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` says that browser is still trying to make network requests even though you have set the context to offline.

This may occur when your web scraping code is still trying to access external resources, such as images or stylesheets.

make sure that your web scraping code only interacts with the cached content.

Try using the `networkIdleTimeout` option when setting the context to offline. This will wait for all network requests to complete before setting the context to offline

```
browser.context.set_offline(True, network_idle_timeout=5000)
```

Comment: So I ran this once with `offline=False` to create the cache. Then turning `offline=True`, I just get `playwright._impl._errors.Error: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`. What am I missing?

Comment: Refer the original answer

Comment: Hello @naved196 thank you for the answer's updates, but [`set_offline`](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-browsercontext#browser-context-set-offline) has no parameter `network_idle_timeout`. Can you make a fully functioning example using [example.com](https://example.com/)?

Comment: try using the waitUntil option to wait for specific network requests to complete before continuing with your web scraping code.

await browser.wait_for_request('your url')

Documentation link attached below
 
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I intercept all requests. after that this code checks if the response is cached, than load it from the cache. if it isn't, store it in a variable called `responses`.
At the end of the test, `responses` content is saved into JSON file called `responses.json`. 
Therefore, during the first execution, all responses will be written into the JSON file, and during subsequent executions, they will be read from it (even if you go offline).

Note this example also uses the [`pytest-playwright`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-playwright/) plugin.

```py
import json
import os
import traceback

from playwright.sync_api import Page, Request, Route


def test_cache_requests(page: Page) -> None:
    def handle(route: Route, request: Request) -> None:
        # If response exists in cache
        if request.url in responses:
            cached_res = responses[request.url]
            # Serve cached response
            route.fulfill(
                body=cached_res["body"], headers=cached_res["headers"]
            )
        else:
            route.continue_()
            try:
                # Get response and store it in responses dictionary by URL
                response = route.request.response()
                responses[request.url] = {
                    "body": response.body().decode("utf-8"),
                    "headers": route.request.headers,
                }
            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()

    def save_responses_to_file() -> None:
        # Create directory if not exists
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(cache_file_path), exist_ok=True)
        # Write cache to file
        with open(cache_file_path, "w") as file:
            json.dump(responses, file)

    def load_cache_from_file() -> dict:
        # Load cached responses from cache file
        if os.path.exists(cache_file_path):
            with open(cache_file_path, "r") as file:
                return json.load(file)
        return {}

    # A dictionary to store cached responses
    responses = {}
    cache_file_path = os.path.join(
        os.path.dirname(__file__), "responses", "responses.json"
    )

    responses = load_cache_from_file()

    # Intercept all requests
    page.route("**/*", handle)

    page.goto("https://playwright.dev/")

    save_responses_to_file()
```